# Unity shell not starting after upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, upgrade, compiz

I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 last night, and unity won't start up for me now.  When I log in, I don't see the 'dash', just the desktop with some icons on it.

I'm running on a lenovo T430 without a dedicated graphics card, so no propritary drivers installed.  The 'unity_support_test' command shows everything is good.

I've tried some of the advice I've found on here such as doing:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

But it doesn't help.   If I use ccsm and turn off the 'Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin' then run 'unity' from a terminal, it starts up, and I get window decorations on the terminal I started.   with the unity plugin enabled if I start unity in a terminal I get a segmentation fault right after the lines:

```
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
```

If I log in with a guest account I get similar behaviour, so I don't think it's a user setting of some kind.

Any advice?  I know I could go with gnome or xfce or something, but I'd rather not go down that road if I didn't have to.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too, don't worry I found out a trick to get it off the base ubuntu drivers.

First when GRUB opens go into Ubuntu somenumbershere... (Advanced) and go into recovery mode. Next you will see a DOS-like window with a few options. Press the down arrow a few times until you get to a option with a name like 'Start in graphics safe mode'. Restart and go into ubuntu. If it starts up correctely you should see your fully-loaded ubuntu desktop. From there you can choose another driver your for integrated graphics and get out of graphics-safe mode :)

I had to guess on some parts as im not in front of ubuntu right now, post any questions.

Comment: A Lenovo T430 with only integrated graphics card is the Intel 3rd generation graphics. This is well supported in Ubuntu 12.10 and up. There will be nothing to install in the safe graphics mode for the OP.